# Script to determine the SSL certificate assigned to each site

Tags: security-certificate, iis6

I have a IIS6 web server with 100+ sites on it. Recently, I was forced to renew my wildcard SSL certificate which all the sites use by creating a new CSR request rather than a renew CSR request. I have installed the certificate and can update each site one at a time to use the new certificate however, I was wondering whether:

1. There is a way to update every site at the same time and
2. If there was a script I can use to view which certificate is currently being used by each site.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for the second item for those that are interested. Create a text file with the contents below and save it with a `.vbs` extention. Then execute it with `cscript myfile.vbs` from the command-line. If you execute it as `cscript myfile.vbs > output.txt` it will put the results in a text file.

```
strComputer = "localhost" 
Set objService = GetObject( "IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC")  

EnumServersites objService  

Public Sub EnumServersites( objSrv )  
    For Each objServer IN objSrv  
        If objServer.Class = "IIsWebServer" Then 
            If Not Ubound(objServer.SecureBindings) = "-1" Then 'check to see if there is at least one securebinding  
                WScript.Echo "Site ID = " & objServer.Name & VbCrLf & "Comment = """ & objServer.ServerComment  
                wscript.Echo "SSL Certificate Expiration Date: " & GetSSLExpirationDate(objServer.Name)  
                wscript.Echo "Days Remaining: " & DaysRemaining(GetSSLExpirationDate(objServer.Name))  
                wscript.echo vbcrlf & "-----------------------------" & vbcrlf  
            End If
    End If

    strBindings = vbNullString
    Next 
End Sub 

Private Function GetSSLExpirationDate( strSiteID )  
    Set iiscertobj = WScript.CreateObject("IIS.CertObj")  
    iiscertobj.serverName = "localhost" 
    iiscertobj.InstanceName = "W3SVC/" & strSiteID  

    tmpArray = Split(iiscertobj.GetCertInfo,vbLf)  
    For Each x in tmpArray  
        If Left(x,2) = "6=" Then 
            GetSSLExpirationDate = Mid(x,3,len(x)-2)  
        End If 
    Next 
End Function

Private Function DaysRemaining(strdate)  
    If IsDate(strDate) Then 
        strdate = cDate(strdate)  
    End If 
    DaysRemaining = DateDiff("d",Date,strdate)  
End Function
```

I pulled this script from [here](http://www.sapien.com/forums/scriptinganswers/forum_posts.asp?TID=4503).